# Write lines from a file to file X based on criteria

Tags: bash

I have a 5000 line text document that I want to read line by line. I want to write each line to another text file depending on how many columns it has. Each column is delimited by a which is delimited by a "|" What would be the fastest way of doing this?

EDIT: I forgot the crucial detail that each the file has sections, and each section is separated by a @,#,or $. Each line must also be outputted into its appropriate section

Example:

```
cat File.txt

@
01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10
11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18
21|22|23|24|25
31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40
#
41|42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49|50
51|52|53|54|55
61|62|63|64|65|66|67|68
71|72|73|74|75|76|77|78|79|80
```

Output (3 Files for example)

```
cat Ten.txt

@
01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10
31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40
#
41|42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49|50
71|72|73|74|75|76|77|78|79|80
```

```
cat Eight.txt 
@
11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18
#
61|62|63|64|65|66|67|68
```

```
cat Five.txt
@
21|22|23|24|25
#
51|52|53|54|55
```

Comment: 5000 lines is actually pretty small. Do you expect to have to do this task very often? If not, then -- why are you so concerned about the "fastest" way, rather than the "simplest" or "easiest" or "best" way?

Comment: Well, this problem is simplified in terms of what I actually want to do. Right now, I'm using cat file|head -$i|tail -1|tr '|' '\n'| wc -l to count the columns and putting that in a for loop and iterating that 5000 times (which I know is slow and dumb) and then putting it through if and else statements to output the file depending on the amount of columns it has

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of this might work:

```
awk -F\| '{ print > "columns-" + NF + ".dat"}' File.txt
```

It doesn't translate the numbers into English, but it would write each line to a file named, e.g. `columns-10.dat` for lines that have 10 columns...

Comment: Does `print >` append or overwrite the files?

Comment: @sampson-chen Within `awk`, it seems to append, at least in the short test I ran... Not sure `awk` even supports any fancier redirections than that...

Comment: creates new per each invocation of awk, but appends during the same invocation. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

- use `awk`
- set delimiter
- print lines with columns number larger or equal N.

For example:

```
$> awk -F "|" '{if (NF >= 10) {print}}' File.txt
01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner to do it with `awk` to find all the lines with 10 columns:

```
awk -F'|' '{if (NF==10) {print $0} }'
```

More generally:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -F'|' -v cols=$1 '{if (NF==cols) {print $0} }'
```

Answer (score 0):

infile.txt:

```
@
01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10
11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18
21|22|23|24|25
31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40
#
41|42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49|50
51|52|53|54|55
61|62|63|64|65|66|67|68
71|72|73|74|75|76|77|78|79|80
$
41|42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49|90
```

Long Awk one-liner (probably unnecessarily long):

`awk -F "|" '{if ($0 == "@") {print $0} else {;if ($0 == "\#") {print $0} else {;if (NF == 10) {print $0};}}}' infile.txt > tens.txt`

tens.txt

```
@
01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10
31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40
#
41|42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49|50
71|72|73|74|75|76|77|78|79|80
$
41|42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49|90
```

Then change the clause `(NF == 10)` to what ever you want each time you run it.